# PowerShell: Cannot find an overload for IndexOf and the argument count: 2

Tags: powershell-remoting

I am attempting to use a portion of a script I wrote to return a list of Local Groups a specified user may be part of on a remote server so they can be quickly removed from said Local Group. Everything seems to work fine until the groups a person may be part of goes below two. When there is only one group I get the following error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "IndexOf" and the argument count: "2".
At line:177 char:30
+                 [string]([array]::IndexOf <<<< ($localGroups, $_)+1) + ". " + $_
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Here are the Functions I wrote for this particular script...

This function will return a list of groups the given user is part of:

```
function Get-LocalGroupAccess
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$fqdn,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$userName

    )
    Process
    {
        $serverPath = [ADSI]"WinNT://$fqdn,computer"
        $serverPath.PSBase.Children | where {$_.PSBase.SchemaClassName -eq 'group'} | foreach {
            $lGroup = [ADSI]$_.PSBase.Path
            $lGroup.PSBase.Invoke("Members") | foreach {
                $lMember = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null).Replace("WinNT://","")
                if ($lMember -like "$userName")
                {
                    $localAccess += @($lGroup.Name)
                }
            }
        }  
        return($localAccess)
    }
}
```

This function sets the User Object (I am not sure this is the technical term):

```
function Set-UserObj($userDomain, $userName)
{
    $userObj = [ADSI]"WinNT://$userDomain/$userName"

    return ($userObj)
}
```

This function set the FQDN (checks to see if it is pingable):

```
function Set-FQDN($fqdn)
{
    do{
        $fqdn = Read-Host "Enter the FQDN"
    } while (-not(Test-Connection $fqdn -quiet))

    return($fqdn)
}
```

This function will take the selection for the group you want to remove the given user from, change it to the proper place in the array, and return the group:

```
function Set-LocalGroup($localGroups, $selectGroup)
{
    $selectGroup = Read-Host "What group would you like to add $userDomain/$userName to?"

    $selectGroup = [int]$selectGroup -= 1
    $setGroup = $localGroups[$selectGroup]

    return($setGroup)
}
```

This function sets the Group object (not sure if this is the technical term):

```
function Set-GroupObj($fqdn, $group)
{
    $groupObj = [ADSI]"WinNT://$fqdn/$group"

    return($groupObj)
}
```

This function removes the given user from the group selected:

```
function Remove-UserAccess ($gObj, $uObj)
{
    $gObj.PSBase.Invoke("Remove",$uObj.PSBase.Path)
}
```

In the script the user name, domain and FQDN are requested. After these are provided the script will return a list of groups the given user is part of. Everything works fine until the user is part of one group. Once that takes place, it throws the error I pasted above.

Please note, this is my first time posting and I am not sure what information is needed here. I hope I provided the proper and correct information. if not, please let me know if there is something else that you require.

Thanks!

Comment: I was running into this after getting the list of Local Groups the user was associated with and writing them out in numbered order. After assigning a user name and FQDN, I ran the following...this is where the error took place:  `Foreach ($_ in $localGroups) { [string]([array]::IndexOf($localGroups, $_)+1) + ". " + $_}`. `$localGroups` was a variable assigned by `$localGroups = Get-LocalGroupAccess $fqdn $userName`.

Answer (score 1):

I went back and was looking at the difference, if there were any, in the variable $localGroups that I was creating (I used Get-Member -InputObject $localGroups). I noticed that when $localGroups had only one item it was a System.String type but when it had more than one item in it, it was a System.Object[] type. I decided to do the following and it addressed the issue I was having:

```
$localGroups = @(Get-LocalGroupAccess $fqdn $userName)
```

previous code:

```
$localGroups = Get-LocalGroupAccess $fqdn $userName
```

Everything is working as it should because I forced the variable to a static type instead of allowing it to create whatever type it wanted.